# SQL Server 2005 : update the status column by comparing two values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table where I have to check the values between column `Value1` and `value2`. If `value1` is less than `value2`, update the status 'Low' in `Status` column, if greater then update status to 'High'.

[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip9xQ.png)

I have tried with this query

```
UPDATE table 
SET Status = If(value1 <= value2) Then 'Low' else 'High'
```

Please guide to a solution.

Comment: what was your result with that query ?

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET Status =
CASE WHEN (value1 <= value2) THEN 'Low'
ELSE 'High' END
```